# How to use Maven to handle a cross-platform (Windows + Linux) Java Native Interface Project?

Tags: java, maven-2, interface, java-native-interface, native

I am currently trying to develop a cross-platform solution that will make some UI components that are not already part of the java standard library available to my java code. I am writing xlib code for X11 and using the relevant win32 api's for windows.

Is it possible (or even recommended?) to setup a java and c code build system using Maven? I need a build system that will compile and link the X11 code and compile and link the win32 code and package them in the jar along with the java interface code. Should I be using Ant to do this?

I have used both build tools before but I don't know which is considered the recommended tool for JNI code.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible using the [native-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/index.html).  I would create a multi-module maven project with separate modules for each of the native interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and not contraindicated. I would use the [Native Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/index.html) or the [Makefile Orchestration Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cbuild-parent/cbuild-plugin-parent/make-maven-plugin/index.html) (if you have an existing makefile), with specific modules or [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for each targeted platform.